# Nesting schemas

Tags: html, schema.org

This is my first time using the [schema.org](http://schema.org) schemas and as luck would have it, the item I am trying to put into the a schema doesn't exactly fit.

To give you an idea. I have a food product, which has nutritional and allergy details which seems to match up well with the [recipy schema](http://schema.org/Recipe). However, my problem is exactly this: It's a product, not a recipe.

Can I embed the recipe schema within a div that has the [product schema](http://schema.org/Product) details?

I.e.

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
        <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Nutrition">
            @* Nutrition goes here *@
        </div>
        <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Allergy">
            @* Allergy goes here *@
        </div>
   </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`additionalType`](http://semanticweb.com/schema-org-adds-additional-type-property_b30861)

> An additional type for the item, typically used for adding more
>   specific types from external vocabularies in microdata syntax. This is
>   a relationship between something and a class that the thing is in. In
>   RDFa syntax, it is better to use the native RDFa syntax - the 'typeof'
>   attribute - for multiple types. Schema.org tools may have only weaker
>   understanding of extra types, in particular those defined externally.
>
> From http://schema.org/Recipe

Example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" additionalType="http://schema.org/Recipe">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Nutrition">
        @* Nutrition goes here *@
    </div>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Allergy">
        @* Allergy goes here *@
    </div>
</div>
```

My guess would be you want to do this because you are selling recipes or something similar. As the quote above says, Schema.org tools may have a weaker understanding of why you've used   `http://schema.org/Product` and `http://schema.org/Recipe` but at least you have prepared for any possible understanding of this use.

Comment: The page isn't selling recipes. It's just the product has nutrition details

Comment: A quick note: just noticed that apparently Google's ["Structured Data Testing Tool"](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) doesn't recognize the `additionalType` defined like that. If defined as a `meta` element it gets recognized as expected.

Comment: @harriha do you have an exemple with meta definition ?

Answer (score 0):

@Nicolas Janel

```
<meta itemprop="additionaltype" content="http://schema.org/Recipe">
```

However, that being said, the additional properties are not recognized. We use two blocks on our site right now and it seems to work as expected on our product pages for Natural search(rich snippets) and Google PLAs. EG.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe"></div>
```

Comment: actually this does answer the first question, and subsequent ask by Nicolas. w00t first comment!!!

Comment: Year later now. Do we still have to use this workaround?

Answer (score 0):

using microdata=> you can go as 'Josh Davenport' Answer Or as Following

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link property="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/Recipe"/>
  <link property="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/X"/>
  <link property="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/Y"/>
  <link property="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/Z"/>
</div>
```

using RDFa

```
<div vocab="https://schema.org/" typeof="Product Recipe X Y Z">

</div>
```