# Using the additionalType schema prop

Tags: html, schema.org

I have a question about the additionalType property.  I want to know two things.  First am I coding it right in both these examples.  And second would it be better not to use it and instead simply use a different type in each instance.  For instance the local business info is repeated at least 4 times per page and I could simply use a different type each time. Same with the description of the services being offered.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/SportsActivityLocation"/>
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/ExerciseGym"/>
    <header>
        <h5 class="Bold DarkBlue TextCenter MyriadFont"><span class="DarkRed" itemprop="telephone">Call 201-230-2036</span><br />
        </header>
        <span itemprop="name">Martial Arts School Name</span><br />
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">24 Bortker Street</span>
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">Brentwood</span>,
            <span itemprop="addressRegion">Ca</span>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">07565</span>
        </div>
    </h5>
    <br />
    <br />
</section>

<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LeisureTimeActivity">
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/AnaerobicActivity"/>
    <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/StrengthTraining"/>
    <header>
        <h5 itemprop="BusinessFunction" class="DarkBlue MyriadFont">Try These Martial Arts Programs FREE for 30 Days:</h5>
    </header>
    <br />
    <div class="TextNormal" style="padding-left:50px;">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="Bold" itemprop="BusinessFunction" >Gracie Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu</h1>
            <p>Learn the single most effective self-defense system on Earth (and the official hand-to-hand combat system of the U.S. Military) from a Gracie-trained Black Belt with multiple champion titles ... Click Here For The Best <a itemprop="URL" href="//www.martialarts.com/brazilian-jiujitsu.html" class="Bold DarkRed"><u> BJJ In Broter County CA</u></a></p>
            <br /><br />
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please address the poor tabbing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

See [Nesting schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031826/nesting-schemas#answer-13032625) for instructions on using additionalType. It basically works like itemtype.